# Running JProfiler on Java 10 (to work with 4K screens)

Tags: java, jprofiler, java-10, hdpi

My new workstation has a 4K screen. Although the OS scales nicely, Java applications that do not run under Java 9 or higher do not. This leaves me with a very tiny JProfiler UI.

As Java 9 is EOL'd by Oracle, it is hard and undesirable to install this version.

JProfiler 10.1.1, however, won't start if I install only Java 10. The change log for 10.1 mentions that support to *profile* Java 10 has been added.

Can JProfiler be executed by Java 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JProfiler 10.1 GUI would not start successfully with Java 10 because of a dependency problem.

JProfiler 11 (this summer) will support fractional HiDPI on Windows with the bundled JRE (and will also support running with Java 10).